# How can I read/write data in background using NSFileHandle?

Tags: iphone

How can I support reading/writing of data in background using NSFileHandle?

Also, how to open a socket between communicating parties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specific to NSFileHandle but probably you need to use NSOperationQueue. If so, you could see ["LazyTableImages"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/index.html) example from apple's sample code.